# Yii2 doesn't work custom standalone validator(inline too)

Tags: php, validation, yii2

In Yii2 I trying to write a standalone validator, but it's doesn't work. Below my code:

Standalone validator:

```
namespace app\components;

use yii\validators\Validator;

class UsernameValidator extends Validator {
    public function validateAttribute($model, $attribute)
    {
        $this->addError($model, $attribute, 'Test.');
    }
}
```

Model code:

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use app\components\UsernameValidator;

class SignUpForm extends Model {
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $confirmPassword;

    public function rules(){
        return [
            [['username', 'password', 'confirmPassword'], 'required'],      
            ['password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' =>    'confirmPassword', 'operator' => '=='],
            ['confirmPassword', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password', 'operator' => '=='],
            ['username', UsernameValidator::className(), 'skipOnEmpty' => false],
        ];
   }
}
```

`skipOnempty`, `skipOnError` don't fix that problem. Please, who experienced this? help me fix.

Comment: I have tested your code and it's working!!

Comment: Yup, this looks fine and should work. Maybe you want this to work as client validation as well? In this case you need to override `clientValidateAttribute()` method.

Comment: @Bizley
Ohhh, I forget about it( I test this code in a client validation. Thank you very much.

Comment: @InsaneSkull
Thank for answer.